# Repair driveway expansion joint sealant during winter?

Tags: concrete, sealing, driveway

We moved into a new construction home this part March. At our first warranty walkthrough, our builder told us that because we were a north facing home, we would have to seal our expansion joint where the driveway meets the garage in order for our concrete warranty to remain valid. They recommended cutting down the felt that was there from when the concrete was poured and then using a self leveling sealant over top. I did this in August using Sikaflex, though it turned out to be a bigger pain than expected to cut the felt down.

Everything seemed fine until this weekend, when we got our first sizeable snow and weather has been bitterly cold (sub zero temps). When leaving for work this morning, I noticed the driveway by the garage looks to have heaved up a bit and, unfortunately, the sealant has pulled away entirely from the garage side for the entire length of the opening. This leaves a crack all the way across, which I fear will result in more heaving as water runs off the cars and out of the garage, and now under the driveway. I'm wondering if there is anything I can do to repair the sealant over the winter or if I'm stuck watching my new driveway get damaged? How likely is this to cause substantial issues over the winter?

Comment: I would be concerned with that much movement! If the slab is moving enough to tear up the expansion joint this is not good.

Comment: I’d get in touch with the contractor who put the slab of concrete down. It shouldn’t move that much.

Answer (score 1):

I use a product called "Pli Stix". I am sure your local home center will carry something similar or order it on line. I haven't tried this product in the winter but I can't see why it wouldn't work. It is packaged in a 30ft coil. You clean out the crack using and air hose, leaf blower,shop vacuum etc to remove the debris. You fill the crack with the material and melt it in place with a heat gun or propane torch. The product melts and conforms to the opening.